# Delete duplicates in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

**tbl_contact**

```
contactID identity(1,1) not null,
contactname varchar(100)
```

**tbl_l_contact_fund**

```
l_contact_fund_id identity(1,1) not null,
contactID int FK to tbl_contact (contactID),
fundID int
```

I have duplicate contact names in my **tbl_contact** table and they were it has linked to **tbl_l_contact_fund**

I would like a query to move all associations of dup contact names from one ID to other ID in tbl_contact and delete the duplicate contact. Can I get the best way to delete the dup's. Thanks!

**Ex:Input**

**tbl_contact**

```
contactID  ContactName

1           Manoj 
2           Manoj
3           Rahul
4           Ajay
5           Rahul
6           Ajay
```

**tbl_l_contact_fund**

```
l_contact_fund_id contactID  fundID

1                   1           1 
2                   2           2
3                   1           3
4                   4           1
5                   6           2
6                   5           1
```

**Final Output**:

**tbl_contact**

```
contactID  ContactName

1           Manoj 
3           Rahul
4           Ajay
```

**tbl_l_contact_fund**

```
l_contact_fund_id contactID  fundID
1                   1           1 
2                   1           2
3                   1           3
4                   4           1
5                   4           2
6                   5           1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? Any efforts?

Comment: Why did you leave two Rahul's?

Comment: @jaques sorry it was by mistake have edited it.

Comment: @andy yes I was looking for an automated script to do this.I can do this manually by picking one dup contact at one time and moving its associations and deleting the dup name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

his will do for you using CTE

```
WITH crows AS (
     SELECT MIN(contactID) contactID, ContactName 
     FROM tbl_contact 
     GROUP BY ContactName
)
UPDATE tbl_l_contact_fund 
    SET contactID = (SELECT ContactID 
                                            FROM crows cr 
                                            WHERE ContactName in 
            (SELECT ContactName 
             FROM tbl_contact 
             WHERE ContactID = a.contactID))
FROM tbl_l_contact_fund a
GO
DELETE tbl_contact WHERE ContactID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(contactID) contactID 
                                           FROM tbl_contact GROUP BY ContactName)
```

Or you can do a direct Update

```
UPDATE tbl_l_contact_fund 
        SET contactID = (SELECT MIN(ContactID) 
                         FROM tbl_contact cr 
                         WHERE ContactName in 
            (Select ContactName 
             FROM tbl_contact 
             WHERE ContactID = a.contactID))
FROM tbl_l_contact_fund a
GO
DELETE tbl_contact WHERE ContactID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(contactID) contactID 
                                            FROM tbl_contact GROUP BY ContactName)
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go for complete sql

```sql
       UPDATE a 
SET a.contactid = c.contactid
FROM tbl_l_contact_fund a inner join
tbl_contact b on a.contactid = b.contactid
inner join (
SELECT * FROM tbl_contact a
where a.contactid in (SELECT min(b.contactid) 
                   FROM tbl_contact b 
                   WHERE b.contactname = a.contactname)
                   ) c
                   on c.contactname = b.contactname

    DELETE from tbl_contact a
    where a.contactid not in (SELECT min(b.contactid) 
                       FROM tbl_contact b 
                       WHERE b.contactname = a.contactname)
```

Comment: And how are you going to update the values in tbl_l_contact_fund?

Comment: just change the not in to in to get the duplicated values :D and include it on your update query

Comment: test your scripts man. where is there a `department_id` or just `id` in his code. Make sure the stuff works before you post it

Answer (score 0):

Giving below the concept.

```
Update tbl_l_contact_fund tt
JOin
(
 Select realId, id, name from tbl_contact ac
  JOIN 
   (select min(Id) realId, name from tbl_contact    group by Name) dt 
        on dt.Name=ac.Name
) ot on ot.id=tt.id

Set tt.id=ot.realid
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
DELETE A 
  FROM tbl_contact A 
  INNER JOIN tbl_l_contact_fund B ON A.contactID = B.contactID
```